# Connecting GeoJSON and TIFF image for deep learning

Tags: geojson, geotiff-tiff, json, deep-learning

I have GeoJSON coord:

```
{
"type":"FeatureCollection",
    "features":[{
        "type":"Feature",
        "geometry":{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[-2,8],[1,8],[1,11],[-2,11],[-2,8]]]},
        "properties":{"anon:size":3,"anon:warning":"WARNING: The item geometries in this collection have been anonymized such that they exist somewhere within the bounding box listed within that item's geometry.","datetime":"2017-01-02T00:00:00","id":"su_african_crops_ghana_source_planet_000000_2017_01_02"}
        }]  
}
```

I have an image from satellite of this area in TIF format:

How can I connect the coordinates from the JSON file and tiff image which will result in a georeferenced image?

Comment: It's not clear what you want to do. Explain your question. What is "connect coordinates and image"?

Comment: How can I connect the coordinates from JSON file and tiff image which will result a georeferenced image?

Comment: What is your polygon data? A bounding box around the image area? Some sample area within the image?

Comment: Some sample area within the range